# Nodejs res.render function not updating html page

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs application that sends values to html page using res.render function. First time it is working fine but next time eventhough the variables are being updated, the html page is not updated and shows old data. (even if I press refresh button the old values are displayed). I am displaying the values in html on pageload.

In Node.js I have:

```
app.get('/dashboard', function (req, res)
        {
            //res.render('dashboard', {originalText: orjText, keywords: KeyWords, relations: Relations, entities: Entities, concepts: Concepts, semantic: SemanticRoles});
            res.render('dashboard', {orjText, KeyWords, Relations, Entities, Concepts, SemanticRoles});
        });
```

And in the HTML :

```
 function onBodyLoad()
  {
    var orgText = "";
    var keywords = "";
    var relations = "";
    var entities = "";
    var concepts = "";
    var semantic = "";
    orgText = "{{orjText}}";
    keywords = "{{ KeyWords }}";
    relations = "{{Relations}}";
    entities = "{{Entities}}";
    concepts = "{{Concepts}}";
    semantic = "{{SemanticRoles}}";
    }
```

Any help ??

Answer (score 1):

Can you upload full `dashboard` and your html, and what is "old values"?
I dont think that they has relation with your question.

Comment: Old value means the previous values set in the variable. For example, if I am sending Keywords="abc" and Entities="xyz" for first time, then if I am updating these variables and sending with res.render(), the changes are not reflecting in html page.

Comment: What engine are you  using ?
And are you sure that your variables are being updated ?