# Nodejs - res.render/send not working for async function with await

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've written some code to create an issue on JIRA using their API. The ticket is created fine, but I'm struggling to communicate this, or any errors, back to the user. I tried using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084661/nodejs-res-render-function-not-updating-html-page) to no avail (as seen in the code).

Basically, after hitting submit, I get the base page back without any results, so can't notify the user whether their ticket was created or not. I suspect the async is messing it up, so I've included a bit more for context.

```js
/* Modules */
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const http = require('machinepack-http');

/* app setup */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/index'), {results: ''});
});
app.listen(2005, function () {
  console.log('Jira Portal listening on port 2005');
});
app.post('/submit', function(req, res){ 
    addAsync(req, res).then((result) => {
        console.log("****** JIRA response: ");
        console.log(result);// standard JIRA API response
        var issueName = result.body.split(",")[1].split(":")[1].replace(/"/g,"");//gets issue name if success (eg. TEST-007)
        var issueDesc = result.body.split(",")[1].split(":")[2].replace(/"/g,"").replace(/\}/g,"");//gets error description if error
        if(result.body.split(",")[0].split(":")[0].replace(/"/g,"").replace(/\{/g,"") == "errorMessages"){
            console.log('ERROR:' + issueDesc); //ERROR:The reporter specified is not a user.
            /*
            * This is not working, html is outputting the correct html code
            * but the user never sees it on their end.
            */
            res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/index'), {results: 'ERROR:' + issueDesc}, 
                function(err, html){
                    if(err){ console.log(err); }
                    console.log(html);//this html output is correct
                    res.status(200).send(html);//never see this html on browser
                }
            );
        }else{
            // Not tested yet, but assuming probably the same issue occurs
            console.log('Created ticket ' + issueName + '. To see this ticket, go to ' + _JIRA_HOST + 'browse/' + issueName);
            return res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/results'), {results: 'Created ticket ' + issueName + '. To see this ticket, go to ' + _JIRA_HOST + 'browse/' + issueName});
        }
    });
});
async function addAsync(req, res){
    return await(createJiraIssue(req, res)); //http post method to JIRA (contains a promise)   
}
```

As requested, the `createJiraIssue()` function (I was hoping it wasn't needed to reduce the amount of code posted in the question).

```js
function createJiraIssue(req, res){
    var login_data = _JIRA_USER + ":" + _JIRA_PW;
    login_data = Buffer.from(login_data).toString('base64');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        http.sendHttpRequest({
            url: '/rest/api/2/issue/',
            baseUrl: _JIRA_HOST,
            method: 'post',
            body:{
                "fields": {
                    "project": {
                        "key": _JIRA_PROJECT
                    },
                    "summary": req.body.summary,
                    "description": req.body.desc,
                    "issuetype": {
                        "name": _JIRA_ISSUE_TYPE
                    },
                    "reporter": {
                        "name": req.body.user
                    },
                    "components": [{
                        "id": req.body.component.split('&')[0]
                    }],
                    "labels": [req.body.area]
                }
            },
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "Basic " + login_data,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).switch({
            error: function(err){ return reject(err); },
            non200Response: function(result){ resolve(result); },
            requestFailed: function(){ return reject("request failed"); },
            success: function(result){ resolve(result); },
        });/*End switch*/
    });/*End Promise*/
}
```

**Sample result**

```
{ statusCode: 400,
  headers: 
   { server: 'servername',
     date: 'Tue, 24 Jul 2018 13:02:05 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
     'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
     connection: 'close',
     'set-cookie': 
      [ 'cookie info' ],
     'x-arequestid': 'requestid',
     'x-anodeid': 'nodeid',
     'x-asen': 'SEN-xxxxxxxx',
     'x-seraph-loginreason': 'OK',
     'x-asessionid': 'sessionid',
     'x-ausername': 'username',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform',
     'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff' },
  body: '{"errorMessages":[],"errors":{"reporter":"The reporter specified is not a user."}}' }
```

Comment: You use `addAsync(req, res).then(...)`, therefore `addAsync` must return a Promise. It does not, because you are awaiting that Promise before returning it. Try with `return createJiraIssue(req, res)` without `await`

Comment: @JeremyThille Thanks for the response, typically, I've somehow not included enough code, the promise is in the `createJiraIssue()` function

Comment: @JeremyThille  In fact `addAsync` is guaranteed to return a promise..   and both the `async` and `await` are pointless here.

Comment: I think we need to see -> `createJiraIssue`

Comment: Why are you passing `res` to `createJiraIssue` ? It's not its job to answer the client

Comment: I've added the `createJiraIssue` hopefully it helps. I'm not actually using `res` in it, so I could certainly drop it from the params.

Comment: Yep, as I thought, `res` is useless and not used in `createJiraIssue`.

Comment: Should -> `}).switch({` be -> `}).exec({`  , looking at the docs for `machinepack-http`

Comment: @Keith I tried that, but node returned an error saying exec could not support that format (machinepack's docs on this are pretty poor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are using `addAsync` function, It is worthless Just use `createJiraIssue` direct inside `request` `function` and make request `function` `async`.

```
/* Modules */
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const http = require('machinepack-http');

/* app setup */
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res){    
    res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/index'), {results: ''});
});
app.listen(2005, function () {
  console.log('Jira Portal listening on port 2005');
});
app.post('/submit', async function(req, res){ 
  try{
        const result =  await createJiraIssue(req, res);
        console.log("****** JIRA response: ");
        console.log(result);// standard JIRA API response
        var issueName = result.body.split(",")[1].split(":")[1].replace(/"/g,"");//gets issue name if success (eg. TEST-007)
        var issueDesc = result.body.split(",")[1].split(":")[2].replace(/"/g,"").replace(/\}/g,"");//gets error description if error
        if(result.body.split(",")[0].split(":")[0].replace(/"/g,"").replace(/\{/g,"") == "errorMessages"){
            console.log('ERROR:' + issueDesc); //ERROR:The reporter specified is not a user.
            /*
            * This is not working, html is outputting the correct html code
            * but the user never sees it on their end.
            */
            res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/index'), {results: 'ERROR:' + issueDesc}, 
                function(err, html){
                    if(err){ console.log(err); }
                    console.log(html);//this html output is correct
                    res.status(200).send(html);//never see this html on browser
                }
            );
        }else{
            // Not tested yet, but assuming probably the same issue occurs
            console.log('Created ticket ' + issueName + '. To see this ticket, go to ' + _JIRA_HOST + 'browse/' + issueName);
            return res.render(path.join(__dirname+'/results'), {results: 'Created ticket ' + issueName + '. To see this ticket, go to ' + _JIRA_HOST + 'browse/' + issueName});
        }

      }
      catch(e){
          console.log("error",e);
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm pretty new to the async game and was just following a tutorial, while your code is certainly neater, it just results in the same problem; my page is not getting the new results when the async function finishes.

Comment: Could you update  implementation of `createJiraIssue` function in your question so I can help in better manner.

Comment: Added it to my question there